# What can I use for mixing/muxing/splitting/leveling audio inputs and outputs?

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, skype

I was hoping to find a single tool that could arrange, in any configuration, any audio inputs and outputs on a Mac.

A specific example follows.

Devices

```
a) Line In from XBOX 360 Audio Out
b) USB from Headset Microphone
c) Audio out from Skype App
d) USB to Headset Earphones
e) Audio in to Elgato Game Capture (Narration track)
f) Audio in to Skype App
```

MIX

```
1) a + b + c => d
2) b + c => e
3) b => f
```

Audio needs to be mixed at different levels. For example, the USB mic level for headset, narration, and Skype can all be different.

I have come close with Audio MIDI Setup, Soundflower, and several copies of LineIn. But I can't split and join audio easily and I can't save the configuration - it has to be painstakingly set up each time apps are relaunched. Rogue Amoeba's paid app Audio Hijack looked like a good candidate but I did not see how to send resulting audio to an application or to a virtual device that could be designated as input for an application.

Comment: e) I'm unsure about… 1) ought to be possible with Audio Midi, using an Aggregate device. 3) should be as easy as setting the device as output for Skype, within Skype. 2) is the difficult one, needing inter-app routing. Soundflower no longer works properly on Yosemite. [Plogue Bidule](http://www.plogue.com/products/bidule/) might be the way to go, but it's expensive - 100 bucks or so. I've played around with a demo briefly but couldn't personally justify the cost

Comment: Yes, I can accomplish (1) on its own as you say but not with (2). Plogue Bidule looks very complicated and way overpowered for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Audio Hijack is great for recording. For routing/combining inputs, look at Rogue Amoeba's Loopback. Unlike Soundflower, it is a paid app -- easier to use, supported, and handles multiple routings/combinations (which can be saved).

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not been able to get Audio Hijack to do it all, it comes close. I have configured it with (e) being the virtual device (2ch) from soundflower and setting the source for the narration device to that virtual device. As pointed out by @Tetsujin, (3) can be done within the Skype app.